# add "www + https" to subdomain in cyberpanle + openlitespeed

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm using the Cyberpanel for my web control panel. my web server is Open-litespeed.
https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/01-installing-cyberpanel/82

Last night I add subdomain and it's totally work fine but the question is how add "www + https" in my subdmoain ?
There is an option in crating domain and subdomains for SSL and can be activate it.
For main domain , I choese the WWW and https.
let see how my domain is open : https://www.avadminsite.io/
I add the **staticcdn** for my subdomain and I expect it open like this : https://www.staticcdn.avadminsite.io/
now it's working like this: https://staticcds.avadminsite.io/

**The cyberpanel has vhost configuration**
vhost config for domain:

```
docRoot                   $VH_ROOT/public_html
vhDomain                  $VH_NAME
vhAliases                 www.$VH_NAME
adminEmails               it is my emain section
enableGzip                1
enableIpGeo               1

index  {
  useServer               0
  indexFiles              index.php, index.html
}

errorlog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.error_log {
  useServer               0
  logLevel                WARN
  rollingSize             10M
}

accesslog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.access_log {
  useServer               0
  logFormat               "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
  logHeaders              5
  rollingSize             10M
  keepDays                10  
  compressArchive         1
}

errorpage 403 {
  url                     403.html
}

errorpage 404 {
  url                     404.html
}

errorpage 500 {
  url                     500.html
}

scripthandler  {
  add                     lsapi:avadminsite1267 php
}

extprocessor avadminsite1267 {
  type                    lsapi
  address                 UDS://tmp/lshttpd/avadminsite1267.sock
  maxConns                10
  env                     LSAPI_CHILDREN=10
  initTimeout             600
  retryTimeout            0
  persistConn             1
  pcKeepAliveTimeout      1
  respBuffer              0
  autoStart               1
  path                    /usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/lsphp
  extUser                 avadminsite1267
  extGroup                avadminsite1267
  memSoftLimit            2047M
  memHardLimit            2047M
  procSoftLimit           400
  procHardLimit           500
}

phpIniOverride  {
php_admin_value open_basedir "/tmp:$VH_ROOT"
}

module cache {
 storagePath /usr/local/lsws/cachedata/$VH_NAME
}

rewrite  {
 enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

context /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  location                /usr/local/lsws/Example/html/.well-known/acme-challenge
  allowBrowse             1

  rewrite  {

  }
  addDefaultCharset       off

  phpIniOverride  {

  }
}


vhssl  {
  keyFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/icf.ir/privkey.pem
  certFile                /etc/letsencrypt/live/icf.ir/fullchain.pem
  certChain               1
  sslProtocol             24
  enableECDHE             1
  renegProtection         1
  sslSessionCache         1
  enableSpdy              15
  enableStapling           1
  ocspRespMaxAge           86400
}
```

**Also the cyberpanel has vhost configuration for subdomains too**

```
docRoot                   /home/avadminsite.io/staticcdn.avadminsite.io
vhDomain                  $VH_NAME
vhAliases                 www.$VH_NAME
adminEmails               myemail@mail.com
enableGzip                1
enableIpGeo               1
index  {
useServer               0
indexFiles              index.php, index.html
}
errorlog $VH_ROOT/logs/avadminsite.io.error_log {
useServer               0
logLevel                WARN
rollingSize             10M
}
accesslog $VH_ROOT/logs/avadminsite.io.access_log {
useServer               0
logFormat               "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
logHeaders              5
rollingSize             10M
keepDays                10 
compressArchive         1
}
phpIniOverride  {
}
module cache {
storagePath /usr/local/lsws/cachedata/$VH_NAME
}
errorpage 403 {
 url                     403.html
}


errorpage 404 {

  url                     404.html
}

errorpage 500 {
  url                     500.html
}

scripthandler  {
  add                     lsapi:avadminsite12677235 php
}

extprocessor avadminsite12677235 {
  type                    lsapi
  address                 UDS://tmp/lshttpd/avadminsite12677235.sock
  maxConns                10
  env                     LSAPI_CHILDREN=10
  initTimeout             60
  retryTimeout            0
  persistConn             1
  pcKeepAliveTimeout      1
  respBuffer              0
  autoStart               1
  path                    /usr/local/lsws/lsphp72/bin/lsphp
  extUser                 icfir1267
  extGroup                icfir1267
  memSoftLimit            2047M
  memHardLimit            2047M
  procSoftLimit           400
  procHardLimit           500
}

rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

context /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  location                /usr/local/lsws/Example/html/.well-known/acme-challenge
  allowBrowse             1

  rewrite  {

  }
  addDefaultCharset       off

  phpIniOverride  {

  }
}
```

Please help.
Warm Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try to add: [www.cloudlinux.wadetest.club](http://www.cloudlinux.wadetest.club) to cyberpanel

1. add the A record to your DNS:
   [add_DNS_record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEL7o.png)
2. Could you navigate to cyberpanel dashboard:  https://YOUR_IP:8090
   Main -> Create Website
   [create_website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnKNo.png)

then it will works
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLVYQ.png)